# Array matches with values on keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

It feels I am going way over my head while discovering the ultimate usage of arrays.

I have two arrays, where the first has main keys, and the value is a count of files attached to that key.

The goal is to match the keys of this first array to the values in a second array, but still mainting (and show) the (value)count of Array-1 -- but for only the values in the second array.

Seems somewhat hazy perhaps, but here are the arrays. The second one has the values that should match the keys in the first.
(My problem is that I keep losing the values of array 1 with every attempt I make.)

Hope you can help me out with this one.

*(working matches are keys like: 125, 2051 & 2214*)

**Array 1:**

```
Array ( 
    [6960] => 3 
    [2214] => 4 
    [2051] => 4 
    [6944] => 2 
    [6938] => 4 
    [1823] => 1 
    [766] => 6 
    [3993] => 4 
    [5896] => 6 
    [6927] => 2 
    [4220] => 3 
    [77] => 3 
    [83] => 1 
    [125] => 2 
    [6618] => 2 
    [196] => 1
    [4072] => 12
    [3718] => 1
    [5918] => 1
    [3388] => 10
    [4500] => 13
    [5968] => 2
    [3000] => 2
    [942] => 1
    [4246] => 8
    [5868] => 2
    [6394] => 3
    [1168] => 1
    [2163] => 1
    [1827] => 2
    [2071] => 8
    [4597] => 1
    [1702] => 7 
)
```

**Array 2:**

```
Array ( 

    [0] => 1024
    [1] => 1076
    [2] => 111
    [3] => 124
    [4] => 125
    [5] => 1301
    [6] => 1409
    [7] => 2051
    [8] => 2214
    [9] => 2636
    [10] => 3246
    [11] => 4838
    [12] => 6946
    [13] => 6955
    [14] => 6961
    [15] => 73
    [16] => 74
    [17] => 8
)
```

Comment: what's the desired output from the match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing this:

```
<?php

$arr1 = array(1 => 1000, 500 => 1111, 1000 => 5000, 5000 => 5555);
$arr2 = array(1, 5000);

print_r(array_intersect_key($arr1, array_flip($arr2)));
```

OUTPUT:

```
(
    [1] => 1000
    [5000] => 5555
)
```

Or, using your data:

```
<?php

$arr1 = array(6960 => 3, 2214 => 4, 2051 => 4, 6944 => 2, 6938 => 4, 1823 => 1, 766 => 6, 3993 => 4, 5896 => 6, 6927 => 2, 4220 => 3, 77 => 3, 83 => 1, 125 => 2, 6618 => 2, 196 => 1, 4072 => 12, 3718 => 1, 5918 => 1, 3388 => 10, 4500 => 13, 5968 => 2, 3000 => 2, 942 => 1, 4246 => 8, 5868 => 2, 6394 => 3, 1168 => 1, 2163 => 1, 1827 => 2, 2071 => 8, 4597 => 1, 1702 => 7);
$arr2 = array(1024, 1076, 111, 124, 125, 1301, 1409, 2051, 2214, 2636, 3246, 4838, 6946, 6955, 6961, 73, 74, 8);

print_r(array_intersect_key($arr1, array_flip($arr2)));
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [2214] => 4
    [2051] => 4
    [125] => 2
)
```

`array_interset_keys` will find the intersection of arrays by keys, not values.  Since your second array is an index based array (not an associative array) we need to first flip the keys and values using array_flip.  Then the keys can be intersected.

Comment: I think this will work but I get a strange result because my second array looks like this:

Array (  
 
    [0] => 1024 
    [1] => 1076 
    [2] => 111 
    [3] => 124 
    [4] => 125 
    [5] => 1301 
    [6] => 1409 
    [7] => 2051 
    [8] => 2214 
    [9] => 2636 
    [10] => 3246 
    [11] => 4838 
    [12] => 6946 
    [13] => 6955 
    [14] => 6961 
    [15] => 73 
    [16] => 74 
    [17] => 8 
)

Any ideas on how to make the count work?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
foreach( $array2 as $key)
{
    $count = ( isset( $array1[ $key ]) ? $array1[ $key ] : 0);
    echo $key . ' has ' . $count . ' files.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhhmm.. i cant seem to understand what you want to imply.. but from the way i see it.. if you want to have the keys of array 1 as value to array 2.. just do this code..

```
 foreach($array1 as $key=>$val) {
     $array2[] = $key;
 }
```

This should grab the KEYS of array1 and insert it to your array2[].

Hope this helps you.. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

This should print out what you need:

```
foreach($array2 as $key=>$val) {
     echo $val;
     foreach($array1 as $key2 => $val2){
         if($key == $val2){
             echo $val2;
         }
     }
     echo '\n'; // new line
 }
```